# add multiple values to multiple select jquery plugin (chosen)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem adding new option values to a chosen plugin.

You have here all the code.

**What i made ?**

- I created an array to add all selected options and the one selected recently
- I add the new array into the chosen input and update it in order to get dynamically the results

**What is the problem ?**

- I have duplicate values in the chosen plugin
- I don't get the result wanted, only one value shown each time i click on new one, not added in the previous selected options !

**What  want to get as result ?**

- When i click on the first multiselect (.second class), this one automatically added into the second multiselect (chosen plugin).
- If i click another time in a value already exist on the second multiselect, this one will not be added again.
- Each time i click on a new option, i get it append and selected on the second multiselect , and will show all the select one not only the new clicked one.

Any fix please ?

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen();

$("#second").on('click', 'option', function(e) {
var getid = $(this).val();
var getnom = $(this).text();
var ids = [];

$('.chosen-select')
         .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",getid)
                    .text(getnom)); 
                    
ids.push(getid); 
$('.chosen-select option:selected').each(function(i, selected) {
ids.push(i); 
}); 

$(".chosen-select").val(ids).trigger("chosen:updated");
});

$('button').click(function(){
        $(".chosen-select").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<select id="second" data-placeholder="Choose a Country..."  multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
          <option value=""></option> 
          <option value="United States">United States</option> 
          <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
          <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option> 
          <option value="Albania">Albania</option> 
          <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option> 
          <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option> 
          <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option> 
          <option value="Angola">Angola</option> 
          <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option> 
        </select>
<br /><br />
<select id="first" data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
   
   
        </select>
<br /><br />
<button class="btn">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 1 (fixes problem 1), only add the option to the `.chosen-select`-element if it doesn't already exists by adding the if-statement:

```
if ($('.chosen-select option[value="'+getid+'"]').length === 0) {
    $('.chosen-select')
             .append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value",getid)
                        .text(getnom)); 
}
```

Update 2 (fixes problem 2), push the right value to the `ids`-array. Not the index, but the value of the selected option. Could have been noticed by logging the value of ids (e.g. `console.log(ids)`).

```
$('.chosen-select option:selected').each(function(i, selected) {
    ids.push(selected.value); // Was: ids.push(i);
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/petervanderwal/oz9knatt/